# Use Model Scope in Laravel Validation Rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a rule like so:

```
Rule::exists('tokens', 'key')
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('state', 'unused');
    })
```

But I'm trying to get access to the actual Token model scopes so I can just just do `->unused()` and not repeat my query.

```
Rule::exists(\App\Models\Token::class, 'key')
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->unused();
    })
```

It appears to get a query builder, but not from the `Token` model.

I've tried some variation with passing the `Token` model in as the argument instead of the `tokens` table name but it just throws errors for `call to undefined method`.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've already noticed; you've access to the query builder instead of the model. What you could do is new up a model and just use the scope directly.

```
use App\Models\Token;

Rule::exists('tokens', 'key')
    ->where(function ($q) {
        (new Token)->scopeUnused($q);
    });
```